# Alteryx for Statisticians- to use or not to use?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-test, alteryx

Is anyone a statistician and using alteryx? I’m wondering if anyone has experience with this or anything to say regarding statisticians using alteryx versus SAS or R. Also, If so, is there a way to conduct statistical tests writhing alteryx.

Comment: Alteryx supports R so it's not one or the other. It's far easier to blend/wrangle with Alteryx vs. either R or SAS. So: data prep with Alteryx, then any advanced processibg with R (and/or Python) right within your Alteryx workflow. SAS is too expensive and has incomprehensible licensing.

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.